# how to check if Split()result is valid?

Tags: vba

I have a function `LastItem` which returns the last word from the string. It works fine for strings with value but for blanks like "" it fails.

I am checking if Split returned an Array. Even for blank string the IsArray() returns true. Is there a way to Fix it.

Errors are mentioned as comment in the code.

```
Sub test()

Debug.Print LastItem("a b c")
Debug.Print LastItem("a")
Debug.Print LastItem("") '''' ===> Error for this one

End Sub

Public Function LastItem(source As String) As String

    Dim arr
    arr = Split(source, Space(1))

    If IsArray(arr) Then
        LastItem = arr(UBound(arr)) '''' ===> For LastItem("") error is [Subscript out of range]
    Else
        LastItem = source
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: check the `UpperBound` too.

Comment: `Split` *always* returns an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if upper bound is greater than -1

---

```
Public Function LastItem(source As String) As String

    Dim arr
    arr = Split(source, Space(1))

    '/ Check if upper bound is greater than -1
    If UBound(arr) > -1 Then
        LastItem = arr(UBound(arr))
    Else
        LastItem = source
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: that worked. never realized upper bound could be negative!

Answer (score 2):

`Split` always returns an array so an `IsArray` check is unnecessary.

How about this? Bail early if the input is a zero-length string.

```
Public Function LastItem(source As String) As String
    If source = vbNullString Then Exit Function

    Dim arr
    arr = Split(source, Space(1))

    LastItem = arr(UBound(arr))
End Function
```

Comment: this works too. I realized IsArray() is redundant but couldn't think of any other check.    +1